# SQL server and c# applications over network

Tags: c#, sql, database, networking

I created a C# application that uses .mdf database and it works perfectly on my PC. 
Now i wanted to install that application on network PCs that can connect to a single database and use that data. 
I tried changing the connection string in application with only changing file path, but it doesn't work. How can i use one PC as server and use program as client application that can connect over network. How do i set up SQL server on that PC, and should i do that? How is this done? I couldn't find any tutorial so far...

Could someone help me a bit.

Comment: Wehn you said you changed the path, what did you change it to? the mdf on a machine isnt really designed to be accessed by multiple clients - you would use sql server directly for that. What did you try?

Comment: On my PC where i developed application connection string goes like this 'code' "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\MILAN\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2008\PROJECTS\program\PROGRAM\DATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True'code'  and when i migrate it on other pc i change only the path to D:\DATA\DATABASE.MDF. Is there a way that i can use this as an multi user application? How do i set up server for this?

Comment: OK, well sqlexpress is a very limited version of server, you would do better to not attach it at runtime, but have it properly within the database, you then would be able to have a very limited number of connectios (assuming you turn it on in SQL express) for other machines to connect.. You can use a similar connectio but rather than attachdbfilename, you specific the name of the database

Comment: OK, i have installed sql server on PC where i want database to be. Is there any way that can i put database on SQL server and connect to it over network with application?

Comment: Yes.. assuming its the same version of sql server, copy the mdf and any other files its created and try attaching it. You can then set the name of your server and database in your connection string.

Comment: Huh i think i have problems attaching database on server. How do i set up new server and make it accessible over network, i have opened the port as someone suggested on the other comment, but that still isn't complete. Is there any guide on how can i start a network server, migrate my mdf or just table definitions and connect to server over network, IP address maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be doing this, this is something that I once looked into myself. I once used a standard base unit for this same purpose and although it worked fine your not really supposed to do it.

You have to ask yourself how important the application is to the business. If its critical then this would be a real bad move for a couple of reasons :-

> 1) What happens if base unit hosting SQL Server dies? or is switched
>   off. Your unstuck.
>
> 2) You will only be able to schedule backups of the
>   SQL Server Database on the local hard disk . If the Disk dies then you
>   will lose everything.

When all is said and done, for the scenario that you are presenting, a MS Access database is probably a cleaner way to go. Access databases, albeit dated, can be hosted on a shared network space and can be accessed by multiple users. ADO.NET is nt too bad and you can still use LINQ with Data Tables etc.

What your looking into doing in your description wont really be fruitful unless your hosting the SQL Server on an Actual Server, as its designed for.

Some people suggest using using SQL Compact, but that itself is designed only to run from a local machine.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Access has a habbit of corruption, but, as you say using a PC as a server which is unlikely to have a raid setup, unlikely to be backed up, I've avoided sql compact even for local apps if I could help it.

Comment: Yeah, I just think if he needs to run this over the network and doesn't have resources such as a "Real" SQL Server, then its not the best route to take. I've used access databases for back end databases, and although they are dated now, I haven't had any problems really.

Comment: I restore an access db shared over the network here on average 3-4 times a week.. because it gets corrupted. :(

Comment: Wow - I've not had that problem once, Only a C# front end communicates with the database, nobody opens the database as such, its strictly back-end, never had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Milan: Go to the SQL Server configuration manager and enable TCP/IP service for SQL Server. As sql server uses TCP/IP for communication.

This link will help you.

http://kristofmattei.be/2010/06/21/enabling-sql-server-2008-r2-access-over-network/